# Unable to remove JLabel from JPanel after adding programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have a class called LMSPanel that **extends JPanel**. This class has the two following methods:

```
/**
 * A method to add an informative temporary label to the Panel until
 * the second Sensor is added.
 * 
 * @param zoneid   - The ID of the Zone.
 * @param sensorid - The ID of the Sensor.
 */
public void justAddedLbl(String zoneid, String sensorid)
{
    infoLbl = new JLabel("Sensor: " + zoneid + sensorid + " added. Please Add 2nd Sensor.");
    add(infoLbl);
    revalidate();
}

/**
 * A method to remove the temporary informative label.
 * Only called when second sensor has been added.
 */
public void removeInfoLbl()
{
    remove(infoLbl);
    revalidate();
}
```

The adding method works fine, but when I try and call the `removeInfoLbl` the Label stays and does go away. I've tried `repaint()` and all sorts of combinations I found online and I still cannot remove the JLabel.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you have a reference issues.  When calling `justAddedLbl` you are creating a new label, which means that if it is called more then once, you will only have a reference to the last label added. It is impossible from the snippet to know for sure

Comment: *"Unable to remove JLabel"*  Why not simply `label.setText("");`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer That is what I thought too, but each method only gets called once for each LMSPanel. So I first call `justAddedLbl()`, then I always call `removeInfoLbl()` straight after. And `infoLbl` is a private field of type JLabel.

Comment: @ciwan Without a runnable example, its impossible to know. Could try changing the text of the label to be sure (instead of trying to remove it)

Comment: I tried changing the text. That didn't work too. My guess is it must be a referencing issue, but can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just quickly tried this, and calling repaint() instead of revalidate() works for me. I think the reason the label is not going away, is that the panel is not getting repainted.

If you are always going to display just one label, why not use setText() like Andrew Thompson suggested.

Comment: I have literally lost my mind over this. Exact same code from yesterday, like MadProgrammer suggested, only difference is I was showing a friend the problem over TeamViewer, and guess what, it decided to work! My guess is, Eclipse and the PC needed a restart? :/

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void removeInfoLbl()
    {
  remove(infoLbl);
  revalidate();
  repaint();
  SetVisible(true);
 }
```

SetVisbile(true) this will be show your current view which is  available..
So try this..

Comment: Do you really think the whole `Container` was invisible ? How would (s)he be able to detect that the `JLabel` was not removed when the `Container` is invisible

Comment: Jlabel was removed but still container is show that j label many times.. so if we use Setvisble(true) again.. it will show the current Container...

Comment: @Ciwan Have you got the Answer?

Comment: Revalidate calls repaint, I'm pretty certain that remove invalidates the container for you and of the component is already visible, calling setVisible(true) will have not effect